# I want to have a string before T in date string

Tags: javascript, json, date

I have the data in JSON like this- 19-04-2017T12:40:00,this is date value ,I want the part before "T" and want to convert this value to and get date structure like for example Wednesday,25 Apr,2017.How to achieve this in javascript???

Comment: momentjs is a good library for parsing dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are can use external library, then [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/) is one of the best.

```
var data = {
    "selectedOnwardFlight": [
        { 
            "lstExtraServices": [], 
            "flightDuration": "1:20", 
            "departuretime": "19-04-2017T12:40:00", 
            "arrivalairport": "GOI_Dabolim, Goa", 
            "segment": 1, 
            "departureairport": 
            "BOM_Chhatrapati Shivaji International, Mumbai", 
            "mac": "6E_Indigo Airlines", 
            "fno": "5924", 
            "dpartTerInfo": "1", 
            "oac": "6E", 
            "arrivaltime": "19-04-2017T14:00:00", 
            "arrivalTerInfo": "" 
        }
    ]
}

var date = moment(data.selectedOnwardFlight[0].arrivaltime, "DD-MM-YYYYThh:mm:ss")
// You need to specify input date format

console.log(date.format("ddd, DD, MMM, YYYY")) 
// After creating moment date object, you can get date in almost any format.
```

Gives **Wed, 19, April, 2017**

For more parse and output formats, check momentjs [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Comment: Do have to convert this value 19-04-2017T12:40:00 into string in order pass it as a parameter in moment???

Comment: Because i get this value 19-04-2017T12:40:00 from JSON as it is without double quotes

Comment: yes, it must be string. And if you are getting the value from json, it should be string i guess. Can you post example data?

Comment: "selectedOnwardFlight": [
    {
      "lstExtraServices": [],
      "flightDuration": "1:20",
      "departuretime": "19-04-2017T12:40:00",
      "arrivalairport": "GOI_Dabolim, Goa",
      "segment": 1,
      "departureairport": "BOM_Chhatrapati Shivaji International, Mumbai",
      "mac": "6E_Indigo Airlines",
      "fno": "5924",
      "dpartTerInfo": "1",
      "oac": "6E",
      "arrivaltime": "19-04-2017T14:00:00",
      "arrivalTerInfo": ""
    }
  ]

Comment: This is my JSON .

Comment: I want departuretime, some how JS doesnt considered it as string ..and gives error

Comment: I have tried this code:
var d=19-04-2017T12:40:00;

n= n.substr(0, n.indexOf('T')); 
console.log(n);
But it works only when i enclose d value in double quotes

Comment: See edit. Just put `data.selectedOnwardFlight[0].arrivaltime` or `data.selectedOnwardFlight[0].departuretime` and it will work

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new Date()`, `String.prototype.slice()` with parameter `0`, `10` to get characters to `"T"`, `.split()` with `"-"` as parameter, `Array.prototype.reverse()`, `.join()` with parameter `"/"`, `.slice()` again with parameters `0`, `15` to get required date parts

```js
var date = String(
             new Date("19-04-2017T12:40:00".slice(0, 10)
             .split("-").reverse().join("/"))
           ).slice(0, 15);

console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use moment javascript library and pass your json value in below function

```
function formatDate(jValue) { 
        var l = jValue.split("T")[0].split("-");
        var r = l[2] + "-" + l[1] + "-" + l[0];
        var o = moment(r);
        return o.format("LLLL").split(',')[0].trim() + ", " + o.date() + " " + o.format("lll").split(",")[0].split(" ")[0].trim() + ", " + o.year()
    }
```

Supplied  "19-04-2017T12:40:00" as parameter o/p was Wednesday, 19 Apr, 2017